# Configure yocto to use protocol other than git

Tags: git, embedded-linux, yocto

I have started using Yocto inside VM in my company's corporate network.. The problem is that by default git port ( 9418 ) is disabled, and running bitbake throws error regarding the connection errors with git..

Is there any way to avoid this, as I cannot enable that port due to security reasons

Answer (score 1):

GIT Fetcher [supports any protocol](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#git-fetcher) beyond `git://`, but you have to specify it manually in `git://` URIs:

```
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/user/repo;protocol=https"
```

The syntax seems to be specific to `bitbake`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find anything related to proxy configuration on corporate network on Yocto [wiki](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Working_Behind_a_Network_Proxy). Solution is to use GIT_PROXY_COMMAND with socat and oe-git-proxy.

Another solution is to download every sources with `bitbake -c fetchall <image>` and then use Yocto [mirrors](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#setting-up-effective-mirrors) with `BB_NO_NETWORK`.

Comment: So I need to contact the Network team for the proxy related information/settings?